# What does the error "type of identifier does not agree with its usage as " " type" mean exactly in VHDL? Does port mapping affect the 'type'?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, intel-fpga, quartus

I have been having issues resolving the error " type of identifier does not agree with its usage " with VHDL. As far as I understand, it means that there is something wrong when assigning values. For example, assigning std_logic to an std_logic_vector or maybe assigning an std_logic to a bit. Correct?

I get the error after i try to do port mapping.Here's where the error occurs:

```
LIBRARY ieee; 
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all; 
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all; 
USE  IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.all;
USE  IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.all;        
ENTITY ALU1 IS
 PORT (a,b,ainverse,binverse, cin:IN std_logic;
    operation: IN std_logic;
        cout, result,resolution : OUT std_logic
   );
 END ALU1;


ARCHITECTURE archAl OF ALU1 IS

COMPONENT adder
    PORT(a,b, cin: IN std_logic;
            cout,resolution: OUT std_logic);
END COMPONENT;

COMPONENT AND1
    PORT(a, b :IN std_logic;
        resolution: OUT std_logic);
END COMPONENT;

COMPONENT OR1
    PORT(a, b : IN std_logic;
        resolution: OUT std_logic);
END COMPONENT;

COMPONENT mux2
 PORT( a, inverse : IN std_logic;
            resolution  :   OUT std_logic
 );
END COMPONENT;

COMPONENT XOR1
 PORT(a,b : IN std_logic;
     resolution : OUT std_logic
     );
END COMPONENT;

 --SIGNAL resolution: std_logic;



BEGIN --ARCHITECTURE BEGIN
andA:  mux2 PORT MAP(a, ainverse, resolution);
andB:  mux2 PORT MAP(b, binverse, resolution);
 resolutionAnd: AND1 PORT MAP (andA, andB, resolution);
  addA: mux2 PORT MAP(a, ainverse, resolution);
addB: mux2 PORT MAP(b, binverse, resolution);
    resolutionOr: OR1 PORT MAP (a, b, resolution);

    resolutionAdd: adder PORT MAP(ainverse, binverse, cin, cout, resolution);

resolutionXor: XOR1 PORT MAP (a,b, resolution);
PROCESS(operation, a, ainverse, resolution, b, cin,cout, BINVERSE) is
BEGIN --PROCESS BEGIN
 IF operation = "00" THEN
    result<=resolutionAnd;
 ELSIF operation = "01" THEN

    result<=resolutionOr;
 ELSIF operation = "10" THEN

     result<=resolutionAdd;

ELSIF operation ="11" THEN

     result<=resolutionAXor;
 END IF;

END PROCESS;
END archAl;
```

The error occurs in `resolutionAnd: AND1 PORT MAP (andA, andB, resolution);`

I get `Error (10476): VHDL error at alu.vhd(158): type of identifier "andA" does not agree with its usage as "std_logic" type` and `Error (10476): VHDL error at alu.vhd(158): type of identifier "andB" does not agree with its usage as "std_logic" type`
.
So, the logical thing to do it to search mux2 which affect andA, andB to see if there is an inconsistency between the assigned types.

The code for mux2 is :

```
ENTITY mux2 IS
PORT(a, inverse: IN std_logic;
   resolution       :   OUT std_logic);
END mux2;

ARCHITECTURE archMux2 OF mux2 IS
  BEGIN
     PROCESS(a, inverse)
     BEGIN
         IF inverse = '0' THEN
            resolution <= a;
         ELSE
            resolution <= NOT a;
        END IF;
     END PROCESS;
 END archMux2;
```

I cannot detect any inconsistency in the assigned types. So I suppose I have not understood the error correctly or something wrong is happening and I am not aware of it. Can someone assist please?

Comment: note: `USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all; ` include twice.

Comment: The problem is that you are not using any intermediate signals. You need to read a basic tutorial on VHDL programming. [example](https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/vhdl_designers_guide/components_and_port_maps/)

Comment: The code for `mux2` is not describing a multiplexer. It seems like you are describing an XOR (exclusive or) operation.

Comment: The error message is inaccurate. The LRM is explicit "An actual associated with a formal port in a port map aspect shall be a signal, an expression, or the reserved word **open**", the semantic rule violated here. A label for a component instantiation statement (a concurrent statement) is none of those and the only place it can be used abstractly is in a binding indication in a configuration specification. An expression is a formula that defines a value. "A type is characterized by a set of values and a set of operations." A statement label has neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`andA` and `andB` are labels:

```
andA:  mux2 PORT MAP(a, ainverse, resolution);
andB:  mux2 PORT MAP(b, binverse, resolution);
^^^^
```

You seem to have connected them to them ports of the `AND` component `resolutionAnd`:

```
resolutionAnd: AND1 PORT MAP (andA, andB, resolution);
                              ^^^^  ^^^^
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Basically I would like the result of mux2 port map to be stored in "something" in order to use it to my AND1 component later. How can I do that ?

Comment: You're designing hardware here, not writing software. You don't "store" the output of a block such as a mux, you connect its output to the input of another block using a signal (which will be synthesised as a metal connection). Looking at your code more closely, (i) 2-input muxes have 4 connections, 1 seems to be missing and (ii) never ever use _positional association_ (Google it) in port maps - it's too error-prone and hence the biggest sin in HDL use. So, given you are designing at gate-level, I recommend drawing a schematic of what you are trying to achieve and to code that up.

Comment: So, for example both 2-input muxes `andA` and `andB` are driving the same signal - resolution. That's not right. Each signal should be driven by one thing.

Comment: more ports are driving `resolution`.